# 13.04 sudo reboot now is not working instead ends up in run level 1

Tags: 13.04, reboot, runlevel

Hi After a recent update to packages on to 13.04 (i.e. this has recently manifested) I now have 5 different systems which will all fail to reboot using `sudo reboot now` this will result in them being stuck in single user mode, and since `sshd` will be down at this runlevel I have to physically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> them down.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in part is to use `sudo reboot -r now` however `sudo reboot now` should really work.  Given this appears to be reproducible I'm posting this in the hope that others will not suffer the PITA that is rebooting a remote server.

`sudo init 6` should work too, but this would skip the user warnings.

Comment: Also having this issue, though the -r flag for reboot does not seem to exist on my system.

Comment: Maybe he meant `sudo shutdown -r now`?

Answer (score 2):

There was a syntax change between [12.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man8/reboot.8.html) and [13.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/reboot.8.html):

```
reboot [OPTION]...                          # 12.10
reboot [OPTION]...  [REBOOTCOMMAND]         # 13.04 and later
```

So to put it mildly, your `now` was never "valid", it was just ignored.

Now, the `now` is being read in as `REBOOTCOMMAND` and that's being used during the reboot sequence and that's generally why everything's getting so fouled up.

The short solution is you just don't need `now`. You never have. That's the `shutdown` command.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but I run into this myself after installing 14.04 and noticed that the now keyword seems to confuse the reboot command.

The command to use nowadays is simply

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shutdown or restart your desktop or server with a simple command in bash. You have to use the commands with `sudo`.  To restart your computer right away,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue... I'm finding that the following appears to work for me...

```
sudo shutdown -h -r now
```

Though it doesn't look like it even would allow everything to gracefully exit first.

Answer (score 0):

To reboot the command should be any one of the following:

```
sudo reboot

sudo shutdown -r now

sudo init 6
```